# Use regex to verify european names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I want to have a regex that test whether a phrase is a correct name or not. It should be something like: `/^[\w\s\.]+$/`

The problem is that the regex above won't match against name like "Noël Burch", since it contains 'ë' character. On other hand, I can't use `/^[\D]+$/` because it will match against phrase like "This is %not a *name".

Is there a simple regex that can match against common European name?

Comment: What about "Fingal O'Flaherty-Smith"?

Comment: or Adélaïde or Aimée or... anyway, what exactly is a **european** name?

Comment: You should probably [read this article](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) first.

Comment: Icelanders must face regexp discrimination constantly with names like Hreiðar. I don't know that there's a list of accented characters that's easily put into a regexp. Your username alone would fail nearly every test.

Comment: What about the [Salish languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squamish_language) that have words like "Sḵwx̱wú7mesh" as proper nouns? Salish languages are not European but they might illustrate the futility of what you're trying to do. And read Catcall's link until you can recite it backwards :)

Comment: To elaborate on what @Catcall said, the likely *real* solution is to not try and "verify" what is/isn't a name because you'll almost always still have someone's name fail to match.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to extract some Hollywood directors names. Most of their names is displayed using just A-Z (and . and '). A few have ë or similar characters. @Catcall: The article is interesting, but I don't know where it will lead me to.

Answer (score 2):

You could check for generic words that begin with an uppercase letter. So for the name

```
someName = "Nicklos Frappapapopadopolos";
```

you could use the regex `^\p{Lu}{1}\p{Ll}+\s+\p{Lu}{1}\p{Ll}+$` which assumes there is only a first and second name and that each name begins with an uppercase letter.

However, I am not sure if `\p{Ll}` will work with European characters.

Edit: Having worked out that the regex section `\p{Ll}` matches European you can now extend the regex for arbitrary long names like

```
someOtherNameI = "Victor PickPockaDopolas The Third"
```

the ragex to match this would be something like `^(\s?\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+\s?)+$`. This matches the above but not

```
someOtherNameII = "Victor PickPockaDopolas The third"
```

This may-or-may-not be another problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing the following:

```
^[\w{list of characters}\s.]+$
```

So basically, if you have something like `Emily Brontë` it should be returned with just the following modification.

```
^[\w{ë}\s.]+$
```

If you know of the specific locales, and your regex supports locales, you should be able to pass these in. Usually passing in the UNICODE directive is something like this:

```
^[\w{L}\s.]+$
```

or

```
^[\w{UNICODE}\s.]+$
```

That being said, using `\w` is still going to allow numbers to be passed in. Is that acceptable for your case? I mean even `Chad 85`, spells his name `Chad Ochocinco`.

Answer (score 1):

Considering all the special letters involved in names, you are probably better off checking for characters that should NOT appear and that people might use if they're misunderstanding the form. These would be:
- numbers
- common punctuation: _ @ , ; : < > | + * / ( ) [ ] ! ? " #